# Identical CP210X USB-Serial converter conflict?

Tags: serial, usb-device

I am troubleshooting an Ubuntu 14.04 system that has two serial devices connected to it. They both have *identically configured* Silabs CP2102 USB-Serial converters.

Device #1 reads inputs
Device #2 outputs data

I am seeing errors that are tremendously difficult to troubleshoot in terms of Device #2.

So my question is: **Can identically configured USB-Serial chips ever have conflict?**

Here is the ouput of `usb-devices`:
{Identical outputs besides the top line of each}

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  7 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=10c4 ProdID=ea60 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Silicon Labs
S:  Product=CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cp210x

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=03 Dev#=  6 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=10c4 ProdID=ea60 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Silicon Labs
S:  Product=CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cp210x
```

Just wondering if this is normal in the peripheral world.

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: Only issue is them not showing up at the correct device name. Change the serial number and then use hot plug rules to make sure they show up right. Also off topic here.

Comment: In addition to being off topic "errors which are tremendously difficult to troubleshoot" is not a valid problem statement for any SE site.  It's a basic rule system-wide that you must be specific.

Comment: As mentioned - this post is not on topic here. Try unix.se or ask.ubuntu. FYI its an issue with device naming - USB serial names are random, not persistent across reboots. Google "persisten usb serial udev rules".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can identically configured USB-Serial chips ever have conflict?

Nope, the OS can usually handle these conflicts.

However, the user/application may not: E.g. on windows you won't know which COM port will be assigned to which device, as this is normally tied to the serial number string. Linux ttyUSBx works a bit different though.

> Device #2 outputs data

A serial device which outputs data continously could be mis-detected as a serial mouse. Some systems may also block serial ports when looking for modems.

Comment: That mouse thing is severely unlikely. It enumerates with usb first so the system would know it's a com device

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it is not necessary to change the serial numbers. Sorry, should have asked this on AskUbuntu. I guess there is no way to migrate this over?